# Нужен хороший сайт с ChatGPT

Tags: искусственный-интеллект, chatgpt

Добры день. Посоветуйте хороший сайт с чатом GPT.

Сайт нужен для учебы, проверки кода или поиска информации.

Недавно начала изучать Пайтон и столкнулась с рядом вопросов, решила попробовать использовать данный чат, чтобы ответить на свои вопросы.

Я перепробовала несколько вариантов, но хотела бы узнать, какие еще существуют хорошие сайты и какие сайты могли бы посоветовать на этом форуме.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Создавать дубликаты своих закрытых вопросов — _очень_ плохая идея. Это отлично заметно.

Comment: И chatGPT не следует использовать для задавания вопросов по программированию. Он довольно часто начинает нести несусветную чепуху и может сильно запутать новичков.

Comment: Самый лучший сайт с GPT, это оригинальный chatgpt от openai. Но будет необходим vpn из-за блокировок.

Comment: Создала дубликат из-за того, что первый вопрос закрыли.

Comment: Дополню @Глеб'а. Лучше научиться правильно гуглить (искать информацию в интернете, в том числе на ruSO / enSO), чем задавать кому-либо где-либо вопросы на каждую проблему. Будет больше пользы и возможность для дальнейшего развития.

Comment: А конкретная проблема в том, что я в процессе изучения языка столкнулась с тем, что я не понимаю какие-то конкретные темы, мне не хватает практики, или даже заданий для отработки темы, которую я прохожу.

Comment: Возьмите Лутца или Васильева и занимайтесь по ним. Там много отличных заданий для практики. И задавайте вопросы тут, а не железке.

Comment: Первое что я делаю, то всегда гуглю, но не всегда могу найти ответ на свой вопрос, а рядом нет, знакомых, кто разбирается в Питоне, поэтому решила восполнить свои пробелы этим чатом. Его слишком много хвалили, вот и я решила попробовать)

Comment: Для Лутца сильно сырая, изучаю на Степике: "поколение Пайтон". Думала пройти курсы у них, а потом книги открывать

Comment: 1) Если предыдущий вопрос закрыли, то, думаете, не закроют и этот? / 
2) GPT не решение вашей проблемы, если `не хватает практики, или даже заданий`, то ищите их. В интернете нереально много ресурсов для этого. / 
3) Дополню @Глеб'а, лично я изучал питон при помощи [самоучителя](https://pythonworld.ru/samouchitel-python). По сути это краткий перевод документации. Ещё неплохой сайт-курс - Питонтютор.

Comment: @LittlePrince, ну, если Лутц сложноват, возьмите Васильева, он очень доступно пишет.